# ¿Cómo ocultar/mostrar una imágenes dentro de una lista?

Tags: html, css

Soy nuevo en esto de html y css, estoy aprendiendo, y tengo una duda... tengo una lista de platos de comidas, y quería que al hacer click o hover en el nombre muestre la imagen del plato, intenté con esto pero no me salió, probando el display none y block me abre el contenedor pero no me muestra la imagen:

```html
   
 <section id="sopas">
     
      <h2>Sopas</h2>
          <ul>
           <li id="mani"><span>Sopa de mani<img id="img" src="imagenes/sopamani.jpg" alt="sopa mani"></span></li>
           <li id="chairo"><span>Chairo $100</span></li>
           <li id="fideo"><span>Fideo $100</span></li>
            </ul>
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
   
#mani img{
    display: none;
}
#mani span:hover{
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 500px;
    transition: border 1s;
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid black;
    
}
.precio{
    font-weight: bold;
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: ¿Que la muestre a lado de la imagen, en un modal o cómo?

Comment: Hola, que la imagen me muestre detras del nombre como un background o debajo... me es indiferente en ese caso

Answer (score 0):

Realiza los siguientes pasos:

- No uses la etiqueta `img` para tener las imágenes que planeas mostrar u ocultar, para evitar el uso de display con sus valores none y block
- Agrega la imagen por medio de la propiedad `background-image`
- Establece un alto y un ancho a cada uno de los `li` ya que al ser un elemento *inline* no poseen mas que el espacio que da el texto que contienen y eso evitaría que se note la imagen como fondo
- Si tratas de mostrar imágenes distintas por cada uno de los `li` te puedes valer de la regla CSS `nth-child()` indicando en los paréntesis el número del elemento al cual le deseas aplicar el fondo personalizado
- Usa `background-size` con el valor `cover` para lograr que la imagen se ajuste y cubra el espacio del elemento que la esta conteniendo

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        li.menu-principal--contenedor-elemento {
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          border: 1px solid;
        }
        .menu-principal--contenedor-elemento:nth-child(1):hover {
          background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/500/500);
          background-size: cover;
        }
        .menu-principal--contenedor-elemento:nth-child(2):hover {
          background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/500/500);
          background-size: cover;
        }
        .menu-principal--contenedor-elemento:nth-child(3):hover {
          background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/500/500);
          background-size: cover;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main>
      <nav class="menu-principal">
        <ul class="menu-principal--contenedor">
          <li class="menu-principal--contenedor-elemento">
            El platillo 1
          </li>
          <li class="menu-principal--contenedor-elemento">
            El platillo 2
          </li>
          <li class="menu-principal--contenedor-elemento">
            El platillo 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```